# Allow invited users to re-share iCloud Photos Shared Album?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, sharing

A non-tech-savy relative has added many photos to an [iCloud Photos Shared Album](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786) on their iPhone. They've invited me and I am a member of the album and can view all of its photos.

They now want **me** to invite a bunch of other family members to the Album.

Looking at the interface, I don't see how this can be done. I see no option to invite other people.

On a test Shared Album I have created myself, I see a link to:

> Invite People...

However I do not see any way to make an invited person an "admin" or "owner" or other such role that would allow them to add other people. The "Invite People..." button is missing in the album I have been added to.

Is there any way for invited people to add others to an iOS iCloud Photos Shared Album?

Can only the singular original album creator add subscribers?

---

<sup>Note: I'm aware that the **"Public Website"** option exists, but this question is about invites and in-app viewing of the shared album. Creating a public website is not a solution.</sup>